# Add view to a recyclerview from adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Is it possible to add a view to a recyclerview from the adapter, without having to use some layout?

Comment: recyclerView itself view so it can not add more views from outside. you can add item in your adapter and then you can set that adapter to recycler view

Comment: @GulabSagevadiya It is mandatory to use a layout designed by me, I cannot use this.
`new Textview(context)`?

Comment: you have to understand use case of recyclerview. recyclerview is used when repetitive views are required. you can provide adapter to recycler view to inflate views in list form.
it's not like linearlayout that can add more views programmatically. recyclerview is called view. linearlayout called as container layout see the diff